# User ID to Username MYSQL in Leaderboard

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a leaderboard with instead of ID, the user name.

This is my MYSQL code now:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_users_score` ORDER BY `wp_users_score`.`score` DESC LIMIT 0 ,3
```

This is the result:

```
user_id| score
2      |    10156
9266   |    2110
3282   |    1960
```

FROM  `wp_users` I need to get the 'ID' to match with the user_id - score like:

```
ID             |  score
Name1          |    10156
Name2          |    2110
Name3          |    1960
```

Is this possible with a mysql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT wp_users_score.id, 
       wp_users.user_id 
  FROM wp_user_score 
 INNER JOIN wp_users 
         ON wp_user_score.id = wp_users.user_id 
 WHERE wp_users_score.id = $id;
```

Comment: Great code, could you add some comments on how it works? It will help the OP and future visitors to better understand your solution

Comment: Thank you, After a bit of googl'ing I have now inserted this code: "SELECT score, user_nicename FROM wp_users_score INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_users_score.user_id = wp_users.ID ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0 , 10" and it works great, but the wp_users table also contains password (encrypted). Will this be a security issue?

Comment: Thank you very much mr. William for your support!